# unable to set status for column in excel

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

In Access I have a Duration_in_days column, to which I want to set a value of "Still active" when the value of end_date column is 0 or null, otherwise it gives the value end_date-start_date. I tried the following code in the expression field property but it will show

'expression not supported for conversion'

```
IIf([End date]=NULL,"Still active",[End date]-[Start date]
```

I also tried to replace NULL with 0, but it shows the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`[End date]` will never be equal to Null because Null can never be equal to anything else ... not even another Null.

Use `IsNull()` to check whether `[End date]` is Null.

```vb
IIf(IsNull([End date]),"Still active",[End date]-[Start date])
```

However since you want *"Still active"* when `[End date]` is Null and when it is zero, you can use the `Nz()` function in Access.

```vb
IIf(Nz([End date],0)=0,"Still active",[End date]-[Start date])
```

I don't understand how Excel fits into this question.